# Attribute name mangled with parent class name (at first parsing) instead of child class name (at instantiation/call)

Tags: python, inheritance, name-mangling

I ran into some unexpected behaviour when trying to test some code, where I was trying to access the name-mangled attribute of a child class (__var). Instead of getting the child's value, I thought I was getting the parent class's __var instead.

**Final Edit**: The child object accesses it's own version of the variable, name-mangled with the parent's name instead of its own. The previously unexpected behaviour is now understood.

```py
class test_parent(object):
    __var = 1

    def getvar(self):
        a = self.__class__.__var
        return a

class test_child(test_parent):
    __var = 2

a = test_parent()
b = test_child()
b.__class__._test_parent__var = 3

print(a.getvar())                       # Prints 1, as expected
print(b.__class__._test_child__var)     # Prints 2, as expected
print(b.__class__._test_parent__var)    # Prints 3, as expected
print(b.getvar())                       # Prints 3
```

Comment: If what you expected happened, it would defeat the entire purpose of name mangling. The whole *point* of name mangling is to make that not happen. Otherwise, you'd just use a regular attribute name.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica not sure what you mean by the point of name-mangling.

Here, test_parent has its own __var (which doesn't get changed) and test_child has its own __var, which it keeps.

The behaviour I don't understand is how: cls.__var (when called from the child class) doesn't appear to give test_child._test_child__var, but something with _test_parent__var

Comment: The whole point of name mangling is to make sure that when a superclass and a subclass both want to use the name `__var`, those uses have nothing to do with each other and don't affect each other at all. Having the subclass `__var` affect superclass code would defeat that purpose.

Comment: Have you used a language with a `private` keyword? This is the closest thing to `private` in Python. It's not `private`, but it's kind of close.

Comment: I guess this is happening because you made getvar a class method on class test_parent, and perhaps also because you aren’t giving it a class as a parameter when you call `b.getvar()`. Because you created getvar as a class method you should be calling it as test_parent.getvar() or test_child.getvar(). Try removing the @classmethod decorator, and make the definition `def getvar(self)` - note you don’t need to change the call because it’s already setup to call an instance method - now does it work as you want/hope/expect?

Comment: never worked in a language with "private" and "public" before.

@barny I've tried by making getvar a regular method as well, and using self instead. I'll update the main post shortly because it still gives a strange result

Comment: @jrmylow because this is *the entire purpose of name-mangling*. It's to *prevent name collisions in subclasses*. Just don't use double-underscore name-mangling if you don't want this behavior because again, that is its entire purpose.

Comment: @barny no, that isn't why it's happening at all. `classmethod` is irrelevant here.

Comment: Edited example to make things hopefully clearer

Comment: @jrmylow you've already been told why this is happening. What exactly is your question? No "issue" remains with name-mangling, it's working [exactly as documented](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)

Comment: so just to clarify this whole "name-collision in subclasses" thing, it just means that when I refer to `self.__var`, if it's from a child it doesn't touch the parent, right?

Comment: ``self.__var`` will refer to the ``__<class>_var`` of ``<class>`` inside of which it was lexically defined. It does not care about the type of ``self``, or how it relates to inheritance.

Comment: Yes. When you use double-underscores, you are *by design* making it so any `self.__var` written in a subclass definition won't access the same `self.__var` in a super-class, because when written in each respective class, the name is mangled *by the compiler*, so `self. _Parent__var` and `self._Child__var`

Comment: @geckos no, the *identity of `self` is irrelevant*, and wheny you call `child_instance.getvar()` `self` is actually a `Child` instance. What matters is *whether the method is **defined** in the parent or child class**.  Not whatever `self` is, because again, `self` will correspond to the *instance*

Comment: Oh, so is kind of lexical binding not self that determines that, thanks I didnt know that, ps: I deleted my comment

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thanks, that explains a fair bit. @geckos not sure what this comment is about, when I add `print(self.__class__)` inside the getvar method it correctly identifies that the __class__ is the child when called from the child

Comment: the confusion came in because of where the name-mangling occurred. I was under the impression that it occurred at method execution time, not at method instantiation time

Comment: FWIW, after so many edits, the question makes no sense anymore, because you're referring to "`cls`" which doesn't exist. I'm inclined to close it for that reason alone…

Comment: i tried to clean up the code so that the extra stuff is removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered with help from the comments:

Python's name-mangling occurs when the method is 'read' by the interpreter (probably not the correct terminology), not when it is called. The tests evidence the process that happens in the background.

When __var is first encountered, it is inside the body of test_parent and is name-mangled:

```
class test_parent(object):
    __var = 1
```

becomes:

```
class test_parent(object):
    _test_parent__var = 1
```

A similar thing happens when `__var` is encountered in `test_child`, becoming `_test_child__var`. The previously unexpected behaviour came about because the same thing happened inside getvar.

```
class test_parent(object):
    ...
    def getvar(self):
        ...
        a = self.__class__.__var
```

becomes:

```
class test_parent(object):
    ...
    def getvar(self):
        ...
        a = self.__class__._test__parent_var
```

That is why the test code `b.getvar()` returns `3` once `b.__class__._test_parent__var` is assigned to it, because that is the value accessed by the getvar method.